# Intermittent 403 during putObjectRequest

Tags: java, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I'm using AWS S3 Java SDK to archive logs to **Google Cloud Storage**.
I noticed that approximately one in every 5k upload requests fails with `403: AccessDenied`, without any additional feedback regarding the root cause.

This is the stack trace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access denied. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: null; S3 Extended Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.access$300(AmazonS3Client.java:394) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$PutObjectStrategy.invokeServiceCall(AmazonS3Client.java:5950) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1812) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1772) ~[aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.807.jar:?]
```

That's all the info I get.
Given the mentioned 1-in-5k error frequency, I suspect this is some kind of bug in GCS.
I normally re-queue failed uploads, but not 403s.
I'm using `com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.807`, as can be seen in the stack trace.

Have you seen anything like this before?

Comment: Do you know the reason for it now?

Comment: @UserASR No, probably some bug on the Google side. I added a special type of retry for 403s which only fires 2 additional attempts and then gives up (so that genuine 403s don't get stuck in an infinite loop) and I noticed from logs that these requests go through on the second retry, so it seems to be some kind of intermittent issue.